# What's the difference between " there is not" and "there does not"?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "there is not" and "there does not" ?

For example:

> there does not exist a unique optimal solution for such problems.

versus

> there is not exist a unique optimal solution for such problems.

Answer (score 1):

"There is not exist" is ungrammatical.
We negate a present form of verb using the do-support.

See how we negate it
"It does not exist".

The same goes to your sentence.
There does not exist would be correct.